# compute x,y coordinates of a point with minimum y value on a bezier curve or an elliptic arc

Tags: python, svg, bezier

I am using https://github.com/mathandy/svgpathtools/tree/master/svgpathtools and I need to find the x, y coordinates of a point on a bezier or elliptic-curve with minimum y value.

```
curve = CubicBezier(0, 1 + 3j, 3 + 1j, 6 + 1j)
_, _, ymin, _ = curve.bbox()
```

How to find the min y value and from this, how to get the x and y coordinates of the point?

Comment: Write out the [cubic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), since you're working in 1 dimension anyway, [take the derivative](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives) which is pretty trivial, and then [find the zero(es)](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#extremities), which given that you started with a cubic, means your derivative is a quadratic curve, and it will have 0, 1, or 2 roots, easily computed using the quadratic formula. Unless you just wanted someone to give you the answer without any explanation. In which case, that'd be silly.

Comment: and of course, let's not forget any math programmer's friend: [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+%281+%2B+3x%29*3*%281-t%29%5E2*t+%2B+%283+%2B+x%29*3*%281-t%29t%5E2+%2B+%286+%2B+1x%29*t%5E3+for+t)